# Good looking underscores with LuaTex and fontspec

Tags: luatex, fontspec, underscore

I'd like to have shorter underscores with `LuaTex` and `fontspec`. And the vertical position of the underscores is too low compared to not using `fontspec`.

Do I have to use some other setup than `fontspec`. It is working quiet well except for the too long underscores.

### Result without `fontspec`

[image: result without fontspec]

### 1. MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[]{fontspec}

\begin{document}
cöde\_nameß

\texttt{cöde\_nameß}

\textit{cöde\_nameß}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I tried https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128817 but there is a still a difference between `texttt` and the others.

### 2. MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\_}{\textscale{.7}{\textunderscore}}

cöde\_nameß

\texttt{cöde\_nameß}

\textit{cöde\_nameß}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I also tried https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81980/61217 but then the font of the underscore doesn't match the `texttt`.

### 3. MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\makeatletter
\let\_\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\_}{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{%
    \hrule\@width.5em
          \@height-.26ex
          \@depth\dimexpr.26ex+.28pt\relax}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

cöde\_nameß

\texttt{cöde\_nameß}

\textit{cöde\_nameß}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Be aware that if you redefine \textunderscore as a rule that it won't copy & paste correctly.

Comment: @AlanMunn see my thrid MWE. It is not working for me. Also the vertical position of the underscore differ form the example without `fontspec`.

Comment: Ultimately this is a font issue, it's not really a case of something "not working". The Latin Modern underscores are the way they are, and there are various ways around that, the best of which would be to find a font whose underscores you like.

Comment: I added another possibility to the old question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384997/2388